# ScrollTo post Offsettop

Tags: javascript, scrollto

I have a `position:fixed;` menu on top of my page with a height of 
175px. I used the code from [scrollTo](http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/scrollto-posts-with-jquery) but the scroll effect puts the 
chosen container on the top of the page, behind my menu.

How can I assign `margin-top: 175px;` to the scrollTo code, so it shows up 
underneath the menu `<div>`?

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZYhJw/29/)

Comment: Place a padding top equal to 175px to the body.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `offset` option of `jQuery.scrollTo`, e.g.

```
$.scrollTo(scroll, {
    duration: 500,
    axis: 'y',
    offset: {top: -175, left: 0}
});
```

In your particular case you'll have to make some calculations in your `scroll()` function as well.

Check this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dekkard/tg2p6qsm/)